# Align-content property is working on a single line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning Flex Box and I have troubles with the property align-content. The property shouldn't have result when there is a single line, but in my case it does and I can't understand why.

The result is that my single line of divs is at the end of my container.
I will be glad for some help.

```css
.conteiner {
    border: solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 500px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content:flex-end
}

.child {
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="conteiner">
        <div class="child">1</div>
        <div class="child">2</div>
        <div class="child">3</div>
        <div class="child">4</div>
        <div class="child">5</div>
        <div class="child">6</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: hi. insert your html pls

Comment: hi,done,I add it

Comment: if you read the specification, you'find out that it doesn't work when flex-wrap is set to no wrap. you did set flex-wrap:wrap, so if you have a single line, it does work and send the content all the way down. You probably need javascript to reset the wrap property when your flex children stands on a single row.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.container{
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the answer.But my question and wondering are why my single line goes to the end(bottom) of my container , when align-content:flex-end property should give result only when there are wrapping and more than one lines and then the lines should be at the end of the container, not when there is no wrapping and only one single line.

Comment: delete this line "align-content:flex-end" and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the reason your code is not working as intended... `The result is that my single line of divs is at the end of my container. I will be glad for some help.`

Is because of this line of code:

```
align-content:flex-end
```

*Also, in your code, you did not close the css function with a semicolon either.*

this means the content in your div that is defined as flex, will have its content placed at the end of the parent element. Likely simply changing this to one of the other definitions for `align-content` will be the outcome you are looking for.

The following article should assist you in understanding ***flex-box*** alignment better:
[Aligning Items in a Flex Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

Answer (score 0):

From my comment :

> if you read the specification, you'find out that it doesn't work when flex-wrap is set to no wrap. you did set flex-wrap:wrap, so if you have a single line, it does work and send the content all the way down. You probably need javascript to reset the wrap property when your flex children stands on a single row.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content

> The CSS align-content property sets the distribution of space between and around content items along a flexbox's cross-axis or a grid's block axis.
>
> **This property has no effect on single line flex containers (i.e. ones with flex-wrap: nowrap).**

here is a possible javascript workaround, not on `flex-wrap` but `align-content` value to get the expected result for both case (a single line or many) : resize the window to wrap an unwrap your flex children

```js
window.onload = check;
window.onresize = check;
let flexbox = document.querySelector(".conteiner");
function check() {
  flexbox.style.alignContent = "flex-start";
  var child = document.querySelector(".conteiner > :last-child");
  var childPos = child.offsetTop;
  child.style.color="red";
  var parentPos = flexbox.offsetTop;
  var childOffset = childPos - parentPos;
  console.log(  parentPos + ' - ' + childPos)
  if (childOffset > 20) {
  flexbox.style.alignContent = "flex-end";
  }
}
```

```css
.conteiner {
    border: solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 500px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content:flex-end
}

.child {
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="conteiner">
        <div class="child">1</div>
        <div class="child">2</div>
        <div class="child">3</div>
        <div class="child">4</div>
        <div class="child">5</div>
        <div class="child">6</div>
    </section>
```

[image]

Comment: what the script is supposed to do? I see nothing in my end

Comment: @TemaniAfif if there is only 1 line, it stands at the top of the container (like if nowrap is set) , if the children (only testing the last one offset position) wraps below the first-line, then align-content is set to end . the op probably thought that if the children were not wraping, then align-content would not be applied (alike resetting flex-wrap to nowrap )  ... unless i totally misunderstood the question ;)

Comment: You forgot to test with Chrome ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif ?? it works with my chrome , just tested again

Comment: I have updated the code to use flex-end and flex-start to make it working on chrome (at least mine)

Comment: i updated my answer with a screenshot made from chrome , funny however. end and start should also be understood by chrome ? thks anyway for the feed back :)

Comment: it seems still not: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_align-content_flex_context_start_end